# python unittests on string form functions

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest

In my case, I'm getting the function the student submitted through an online course website in text form.

for example, my input will get

```
payload['content'] = '''
  def my_func(a):
    return a + 1
'''
```

in normal scenario, I would run

```
import my_func

assert 2, my_func(1)
```

how would go about solving this?

Comment: Are you trying to evaluate the function, and then compare the output?

Comment: You could use `exec(payload['content'])`; then `my_func` would be defined. However, this isn't safe as you don't know ahead of time what code a student might submit.

Comment: @chepner, yes, I would prefer a safer method.

Comment: @WebQube Then you need some sort of sandbox environment; how to set that up is probably beyond the scope of Stack Overflow. The simplest thing I can think of is to just use `exec` in a virtual machine, although you would still want to configure the VM to disallow any network connections to make sure the code can't affect anything outside the VM.

Comment: The code runs in a docker. does that make it safer? I guess so.

Comment: @chepner write your answer and i'll approve.